# Combine multiple html projects into a single website in visual studio

Tags: html, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have several html projects in the same visual studio solution. I am using vs2012 Currently these are deployed in separate virtual directories in IIS, but more and more projects are being created and the number of virtual directories is getting harder to manager.

As part of the build I want to combine the projects in one output directory which I can map in a single virtual directory in IIS.

I have tried creating directories and copying into them, but I have only got this working on a per project basis ie. each project still ends up in it's own directory, not merged together.

Can anyone suggest how the output of these projects could be combined?